# How to match multiple values in Kusto Query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Say I have a table like this

```
data = (Name:string, Team:string)[
   "Toma","Team1",
   "Tomb","Team2",
   "Tomc","Team3",
   "Tomd","Team2",
]
```

and I want to find member in team1 and team2.
The way I write the query now is using

```
data
| where Team == "Team1" or Team == "Team2"
```

and it gives me what I want.
Is there a way do that in a list so I do not need to write `Team == "XXX"`

```
let Teams ={ "Team1" "Team2"} 
data   
| where Team (magic here) in Teams
```

So I can modify the Teams variable and get the result I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can simply write what you wanted:

```
let Teams = dynamic(["Team1","Team2"]);
data   
| where Team in (Teams)
```

Comment: thanks, it solve my problem. So can I have a follow up question. What does the "( )" do here? Indicating it is a variable?

Comment: It is just a syntax, you can put a variable or a list of literal values (inline), if you want to embed a query you need double parenthesis "(( ))" , see more in the "in" operator docs

Comment: What's the difference between using dynamic() vs pack_array() in this context ?

```
let Teams = dynamic(["Team1","Team2"]);
let Teams = pack_array("Team1","Team2");

data   
| where Team in (Teams)

```